# Can't grab edges/corners of windows for resizing

Tags: macos

I have a problem with window resize since I've update my OS X to El Capitan edition.

I can not "catch" the edges and corners of windows to drag them for resizing.

[image]

It's not dependent on the app.

Magic moment when problem resolved by invisible man help. It's working for a couple of seconds and problem come back after successful screen size changes stops:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxvlwUMnoR4

Comment: What does "sometime with G help" mean?

Comment: With nothing reasonable. same window, same session, same system state. Like invisable man press the magic button inside OS X logic to release that problem for a couple seconds.

Comment: What app are you using to create that circle when you click in the window header?

Comment: it's basic QuickTime app within OS X

Comment: Are you using a wired/wireless mouse or a trackpad of some sort?

Comment: It's wired USB mouse. It's not a position problem you can see it on the second video.

Comment: Try this: Go to ~/Library/Preferences and move `com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist` to your Desktop and restart. Then open System Preferences > Mouse and reset your mouse preferences.